# Creating record through list LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I created  record through list but problem is only `Name`  value populated in that object the remaining fields are empty.Maping fields from Object.

```
import cTName from '@salesforce/schema/Coaching_Templates__c.Name';
import cTType from '@salesforce/schema/Coaching_Templates__c.Coaching_Template_Type__c';
import cTStartDate from '@salesforce/schema/Coaching_Templates__c.Start_Date__c';
import cTEndDate from '@salesforce/schema/Coaching_Templates__c.End_Date__c';
import cTActive from '@salesforce/schema/Coaching_Templates__c.Active__c';
import cTCountry from '@salesforce/schema/Coaching_Templates__c.Country__c';
```

The Object which hold the data

```
@track cTemplateList={
    Name:cTName,                
    Type:cTType,   
    Active:cTActive,
    Start_Date:cTStartDate,
    End_Date:cTEndDate,
    Country:cTCountry
          
};
```

Assign value to that object

```
  getName(event) {
     let name = event.target.value;
      this.cTemplateList.Name = name;
  }
  getType(event) {
    let type = event.target.value;
    this.cTemplateList.Type = type;
 }
 getStartDate(event) {
  let startDate = event.target.value;
  this.cTemplateList.Start_Date = startDate;
 
}
getEndDate(event) {
  let endDate = event.target.value;
  this.cTemplateList.End_Date = endDate;
  

}
getActive(event) {
  let active = event.target.checked;
  this.cTemplateList.Active = active;
}
getCountry(event) {
  let country = event.target.value;
  this.cTemplateList.Country = country;
}
```

Method for Insertion

```
 insertCTemplate(){
    console.log('ok');
    insertCTemplateMethod({cTemplateObj:this.cTemplateList})
        .then(result=>{
          
            this.cTemplateList={};
           this.cTamplateid=result.Id;
            window.console.log('after save' +  this.cTamplateid );
            
            const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
              title:'Success!',
              message:'Account created successfully',
              variant:'success'
            });
            //console.log('??????' +this.accountid);
            //this.saveCoachingTemplateSecton(this.cTamplateid);
            this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
        })
        .catch(error=>{
           this.error=error.message;
           window.console.log(this.error);
        });
      
  }
```

Apex class method

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static  Coaching_Templates__c insertCTemplateMethod( Coaching_Templates__c cTemplateObj){
        try {
            
                system.debug('>>>>>' + cTemplateObj );
          insert cTemplateObj;
            return cTemplateObj;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

Onchange event from Template

```
  <div class="slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                                <lightning-input type="text" label="Name" value={cTemplateList.Name} onchange={getName}></lightning-input>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class=" slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                                <template if:true={typeValues.data}>
                                    <lightning-combobox name="type" label="Type" value={cTemplateList.Type}
                                        options={typeValues.data.values} onchange={getType}>
                                    </lightning-combobox>
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                                <lightning-input type="date" label="Start Date" value={cTemplateList.Start_Date} onchange={getStartDate}></lightning-input>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class=" slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                                <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="Active"  value={cTemplateList.Active}  onchange={getActive}></lightning-input>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>

                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                                <lightning-input type="date" label="End date " value={cTemplateList.End_Date} onchange={getEndDate}></lightning-input>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class=" slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                                <template if:true={countryValues.data}>
                                    <lightning-combobox name="progress" label="Lead Source" value={cTemplateList.Country}
                                        options={countryValues.data.values} onchange={getCountry}>
                                    </lightning-combobox>
                                </template>
                            </div>
                        </td>
```

**Note** Record created successfully but only with name field the remaining field are empty.Why the remaining field are empty?? Any One Know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use field imports, you use their properties to assign values.

```
@track cTemplateList={
    [cTName.fieldApiName]:'',
    [cTType.fieldApiName]:'',
    [cTActive.fieldApiName]:'',
    [cTStartDate.fieldApiName]:'',
    [cTEndDate.fieldApiName]:'',
    [cTCountry.fieldApiName]:''
}
```

And then you assign changed values in the same manner:

```
getName(event) {
  this.cTemplateList[ctName.fieldApiName] = event.target.value
}
```

This will map the field value to the proper name.

Comment: i am  confused  why we need it like that. please check the link

Comment: https://www.w3web.net/insert-a-record-of-account-lightning-web-component/

Comment: fieldApiName --- put field api name like  startdate__c ???

Comment: @fado That blog post is wrong. It happens to work only because they named the field names correctly, perhaps by accident. The record you pass to the server must be in `{ fieldName: value }` format. And no, `fieldApiName` is not a coincidence, it is a variable that you use to get the field name from the imported token.

Comment: kindly  check my code above  i already use ```cTName``` as a ```fieldApName``` and  the code  give to me is different. so whats  be  that  object ``` cTemplateList``` like??

Comment: what is cTName??

Comment: thank you so much now i got you.